# @polkadot/typegen 9.1.1 use the missing types

Tags: polkadot-js

generated files `augment-api-runtime.ts` has a line `augment-api-runtime.ts:136`
which looks like this:

```
      /**
       * Return all the current data for a block in a single runtime call.
       **/
      currentAll: AugmentedCall<ApiType, () => Observable<ITuple<[Option<BlockV2>, Option<Vec<ReceiptV0>>, Option<Vec<TransactionStatus>>]>>>;
```

typescript justly throwing errors: `Cannot find name 'ReceiptV0'` and `Cannot find name 'TransactionStatus'`.

I suppose this line have to be something like this::

```
      /**
       * Return all the current data for a block in a single runtime call.
       **/
      currentAll: AugmentedCall<ApiType, () => Observable<ITuple<[Option<BlockV2>, Option<Vec<EthReceiptV3>>, Option<Vec<EthTransactionStatus>>]>>>;
```

Look at this code:
https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/12750bc83d8d7f01957896a80a7ba948ba3690b7/packages/types/src/interfaces/eth/runtime.ts#L180

Answer (score 2):

It is not missing the types, rather it is applying the type names exactly as specified in the pre-v14 metadata. It doesn't apply transformations to the types received in the metadata.

So with that in mind, it is generally suggested to use a Substrate base that supports v14 metadata where all the types and their definitions are carried in the metadata itself - which removes the need to define your own types.

If you need to use a v13 metadata, for type generation to work correctly, you would need to add the corresponding types for your runtime to a definitions.ts file and pass it along with generation. This would mean either defining the specific types missing of providing aliases from the way it is described in the metadata to the names it is defined as as part of the js api runtime/rpc definitions.

Comment: what is the type `ReceiptV0`? and why it is only once mentioned in the whole repository? Please correct me, but it looks super weird, can you share the link on a declaration of this type?

Comment: I guess you was wrong, this bag was changed [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/commit/69afe1a2033e935436992942704770657a397a04#diff-95f44eb483d8831f1bcf06c2ac3c6971617525edb91b423ada233dc0876c6453R183)